# Invoice::setDueDate() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, Xero API using calcinai

Tags: php, wrapper, xero-api

I am following this [wrapper](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php)

I have this error: **Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::setDueDate() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, string given**

This is my code:

```
try{
            $lineitem = new LineItem($this->_xi);
            $lineitem->setAccountCode('200')
            ->setQuantity('5.400')
            ->setDescription('this is awesome test')
            ->setUnitAmount('9900.00');

            $contact = new Contact($this->_xi);
            $contact->setName("John Doe")
                ->setFirstName("John")
                ->setLastName("Doe")
                ->setEmailAddress("johngwapo@hot.com")
                ->setContactStatus(Contact::CONTACT_STATUS_ACTIVE);



            $invoice = new Invoice($this->_xi);
            $invoice->setType(Invoice::INVOICE_TYPE_ACCREC)
                ->setStatus(Invoice::INVOICE_STATUS_AUTHORISED)
                ->setContact($contact)
                //->setDate(\DateTimeInterface::format("Y-m-d"))
                ->setDueDate("2018-09-09")
                ->setLineAmountType(Invoice::LINEAMOUNT_TYPE_EXCLUSIVE)
                ->addLineItem($lineitem)
                ->setInvoiceNumber('10')
                ->save();



        }catch ( Exception $e ){
            $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('[Xero-createContact]-' . $e->getMessage());
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
```

When I tried doing it like this:

```
->setDueDate(\DateTimeInterface::format("Y-m-d"))
```

I got this error instead: **Fatal error: Non-static method DateTimeInterface::format() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context**

This is the function of setDueDate that I am calling:

```
 /**
     * @param \DateTimeInterface $value
     * @return Invoice
     */
public function setDueDate(\DateTimeInterface $value)
    {
        $this->propertyUpdated('DueDate', $value);
        $this->_data['DueDate'] = $value;
        return $this;
    }
```

I'm really lost here as to how do I use this DateTimeInterface and how can I even set a future date using it, and how do I solve all this errors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first error says, that the `->setDueDate($date)` method expects an object which implements the [DateTimeInterface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php), but you supplied just a string instead `->setDueDate("2018-09-09")`

The second error says, that the `format($format)` method cannot be called statically. It expects a format pattern, and formats an existing object to a string according to the pattern provided. However you tried to call it statically, providing the date string instead of the format pattern - no wonder it failed. You need the [`createFromFormat($format, $date_string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method, which creates a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from a string, not the other way around.

The solution is to create an object that implements the DateTimeInterface. For example [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) *(which is the same, but is never modified)*. I suggest DateTime if you may modify this value later on.

So change this line:

```
->setDueDate("2018-09-09")
```

to this:

```
->setDueDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2018-09-09"))
```

and it should work like a charm.

Comment: The other posted answer worked but I wonder why the author deleted it. Thank you for this and for the explanation it really helps a lot.